# Spell correction for sentiment classification?

Tags: java, spell-checking, text-classification

I am currently doing text classification and find out that some document in corpus has spelling mistakes like "goes" is written as "geos" and "available" is written as "avaliable". I am 524 smart stop words to remove stop words. This spelling mistakes are causing stop words not to removed correctly from corpus and reside there which may be effecting my classifier performance. I am using 20 News Group data set.

What should i use for spell corrections for English language in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Pls Refer this You may get an idea
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-spelling-java/

Comment: i give it a try but came to know that google has closed their spell checking service long time ago i think Nov, 2013 after which API above mentioned become useless. I have started using Jazzy API for spell checking. It very easy and good to use..